# Formula for the omission and the commission errors

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix

I'm confused by the formula for the commission-error and the omission-error as it was stated a bit differently in a paper I've read, compared to the one I'm giving below (maybe the authors changed that because of the context of a change detection, not a casual classification).

Are these the correct formula for a given class?

$$ commisionError = \frac{FP}{FP + TP} = \frac{FP}{totalPredicted} $$
$$ omissionError = \frac{FN}{FN + TP}  = \frac{FN}{totalReference}$$

Where:

- FP: The false positive.
- TP: The true positive.
- FN: The false negative.
- TN: The true negative.

If we had only two classes, should these two errors be calculated for the two classes, or is there a way to infer the errors of the second class from those of the first one?

I'm asking because it's clear that for a two-classes case we have:

$$ FP_{class1} = FN_{class2} $$

$$ FN_{class1} = FP_{class2} $$

Comment: This will help you with very detailed steps: http://gsp.humboldt.edu/olm_2015/courses/gsp_216_online/lesson6-2/metrics.html

Comment: Yeah, those are the formulas I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

### Arithmetic

We have four numbers: TP, FP, TN, FN that sum to $M$, total number of samples:
$$
TP + FP + TN + FN = M
$$

$M$ is usually known. So if you know any 3 of those 4 numbers, you can calculate the forth one.

Those four numbers are base of many scores (aka coefficients, rates, values), see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). By juggling with above formula you can find many relations between these scores.

### Formulas

*commisionError* and *omissionError* are not very common names. You ask if those are correct. If this is the definition, they are correct by definition. It is really hard to answer, as you say:

> Are these the correct formula for a given class?

There is no given class, because using TP, TN, ... implies that there are exactly two classes. So you may want clarify what you mean by *given class*.

Comment: Yes, I was asking in the context of two classes, as I wasn't sure if the errors mentioned above should be calculated for both classes, and whether the formulas were correct at all. I recently came across the `FPR` and the `FNR` which were calculated in a way that $FPR_{class1} = FNR_{class2}$ and vice versa.

Comment: If you have only two classes, than FPR = FP/(FP+TP) and FNR = FN/ (FN+TP). No class subindex. If there were more classes, situation gets more complicated

Comment: The formulas for the `FPR` and the `FNR` you gave above are different from the ones I've found [online](https://gerardnico.com/data_mining/error_rate). Do you have a reference? As for the `omission` and `commission errors`, I got them from [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introductory-Digital-Image-Processing-Perspective/dp/0131453610). The problem actually with all these performance indicators is that sometimes you find different formulas for the same indicator, and it's one reason why I was confused.

Comment: @Hakim I just discovered that I didn't answer to your comment. You are right, my FPR formula is not correct (maybe I did a typo). Right formula: FPR = FP/(FP+TN) if it still matters... Sorry for my mistake. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)